Digest Auth in Node JS
I have one api by which I can send SMS, so but the issue is we can only use it with Digest Auth, I have tried it using it with axios its not working, then I call this api with Postman and select the Authorization type to Digest Auth, by this configuration its start working, but now I want to use that api in my applications, so I am crating a MERN application so I have tried many ways to figure it out that how I can use Digest Auth in Node Js but every solution I tried is not working, so if anyone knows any solution so please let me know, thanks in Advance

What is your last try?

Where is your code? Have you copied the request from postman and tried it? You can export them as curl or view the send request.
